# Combine a XAML (WPF) app in Unity with MixedRealityToolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I am new to HoloLens development, so I hope this is not a too basic thing to ask. I currently have developed a 2D XAML (WPF/UWP) interface in Visual Studio which is being developed for and tested on a HoloLens. Everything is working great and the application is coming along great.

Now I would like to use a certain feature of the [MixedRealityToolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity) for Unity to implement some sort of Surface Magnetism so I can stick the interface to a wall or table. Exactly like explained and shown in [the example](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/master/Assets/HoloToolkit-Examples/SpatialMapping/SpatialProcessingSurfaceMagnetism.md) of the toolkit.

The thing now is that this toolkit is for Unity and specifically for D3D. Do any of you know how I can take my XAML application and open/use it in Unity to get it working with the toolkit. If this is not possible, do any of you know of alternatives or what next steps I could take? Any pointers?

EDIT: A possible other solution could be if I could somehow remake the WPF app in Unity. But I would like it to be consistent with UWP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a toolkit in the Unity Asset Store called NoesisGUI, which lets you define interfaces in XAML. It's not 100% compatible with UWP or WPF, but at least it would let you work in XAML and should be reasonably easy to adapt to. If you can't find a better way, this might be the least horrible alternative.

Comment: I am going to check this one out! I will keep you posted! Thanks

Comment: I didn't really manage to make it a 100% compatible like you mentioned, but thanks for the suggestion. I tried to make it work with NoesisGUI, but in the end I remade the whole UI in native Unity. If you want to design your UI in XAML though, this is a good solution.